# $e^{e^x} = 10^{10} x^{10}e^{10^{10} x^{10}}$ - Find $x$ (G.H. Hardy)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request, contest-math

> Approximate the large positive root of the equation
> $$e^{e^x} = 10^{10} x^{10}e^{10^{10} x^{10}}$$
>
> (attributed to G.H. Hardy)

This is a great problem which I can find no verifiable source or discussion of online.  Is there a source where Hardy actually asks this question?  How did Hardy (or others) approach it?

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/319-d-6-8-to-find-an-approximation-to-the-large-position-root-of-the-equation/028F00B9087E55ED08CD103EBD6361DE

Comment: @TravisWillse: Thank you for the reference. There is much to learn from Hardy's work, both with the 'little problems' he dealt with and heftier stuff. I've always found his presentation erudite, direct, and graceful.

Comment: In terms of the $-1$ branch of the Lambert $W$ function, $$
x \approx  - 10 \cdot W_{ - 1}\! \left( { - \frac{1}{{100}}} \right) = 64.727751243 \ldots \,.
$$ The absolute error turns out to be less than $10^{-16}$.

Comment: @Gary Care to turn that into an answer, accessible to those without background in the $W$ function? ([Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) was inscrutable.)

Comment: It turns out that Wolfram Alpha cannot get the large root easily, but it can find the maximum after $\ln$ of both sides implying a root near $x=63$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Be%5Ex-ln%28%2810+x%29%5E10+e%5E%2810+x%29%5E10%29%5D%3D0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Hardy addresses the problem in this 1910 note](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/319-d-6-8-to-find-an-approximation-to-the-large-position-root-of-the-equation/028F00B9087E55ED08CD103EBD6361DE), and I'll summarize his method.

Taking the natural logarithm of both sides gives
$$e^x = 10 \log 10 + 10 \log x + 10^{10} x^{10} ,$$
so we may as well write $$e^x = 10^{10} x^{10} (1 + \epsilon)$$
where $0 < \epsilon < 10^{-8}$).
Taking the logarithm again gives
$$x = 10 \log 10 + 10 \log x + \epsilon',$$
and $0 < \epsilon' < \epsilon$.

Since $\log 10 = 2.302\ldots$ and $\epsilon' < 1$, we must have
$$23 + 10 \log x < x < 24 + 10 \log x .$$

From here we can bootstrap lower and upper bounds for $x$. There are many ways to proceed here, but I'll continue to follow Hardy's method.

First, since $\log 10 > 2.3$, $x > 10 \log 10 > 23$, hence $\log x > 3$, and substituting gives
$$x > 23 + 10 (3) > 23 + 30 = 53.$$
We repeat the process using our new lower bound for $x$: $\log x > \log 53 > 3.9$ (Hardy erroneously writes $\log 53 > 4$, but that makes no difference for the conclusion), so
$$x > 23 + 10 (3.9) > 23 + 39 = 62 ,$$
and iterating twice more gives $x > 63$ and then $x > 64$.

Finding an upper bound is just a little trickier. Taking the logarithm yet again gives
$$\log x = \log 10 + \log \log x + \log \left(1 + \frac{23 + \epsilon'}{10 \log x}\right) .$$
The last term is smaller than $\frac{24}{40} = \frac35$, and since $\frac{\log \log x}{\log x}$ decreases when $x > e$, we have
$$\frac{\log \log x}{\log x} < \frac{\log \log 64}{\log 64} < \frac25. $$
So, $\log x < \log 10 + \frac{2}{5} \log x + \frac{3}{5},$ thus $\log x < 1 + \frac{5}{3} \log 10$, so $x < 127$, hence
\begin{align*}
x &< 24 + 10 \log 127 < 73 \\
x &< 24 + 10 \log \phantom{1}73 < 67 .
\end{align*}
So, we've shown Hardy's bounds, $$\boxed{64 < x < 67} .$$ Repeating the above computations but keeping $2$ more decimal places, for example, gives the tighter bounds
$$\boxed{64.71 < x < 64.74} ,$$

**Remark** Since $\epsilon' \approx 0$, the solution of the original equation is close to the (larger) solution of
$x = 10 \log 10 + 10 \log x$, namely
$$-10 W\left(-1, -\frac1{100}\right) = 64.7277512439\ldots,$$
where $W(-1, \,\cdot\,)$ is the $-1$ branch of the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Solving the original equation numerically gives that the above approximation $x \approx -10 W\left(-1, -\frac1{100}\right)$ has relative error $< 10^{-28}$—put another way, the large factor $10^{10} x^{10}$ in the original equation is virtually irrelevant to finding the solution.

> Hardy GH. 319. [D. 6. 8.] "To find an approximation to the large position [sic] root of the equation $e^{e^x} = 10^{10} x^{10}e^{10^{10} x^{10}}$." *The Mathematical Gazette*. 1910; **5**(88):333-334. doi:10.2307/3603416

Comment: Thank you.  How did you bound $\epsilon < 10^{-9}$?

Comment: Since $\log x < x^10$, $\epsilon = \frac{10 \log 10 + 10 \log x}{10^{10} x^{10}} = 10^{-9}(x^{-10}\log 10 + 1) < 10^{-9} (\log 10 + 1) < 4 \cdot 10^{-9}$, which is the bound that Hardy gave and which I meant to write---and I'll edit my answer accordingly. But being slightly more careful will certainly give you $10^{-9}$---indeed, the actual value of $\epsilon$ turns out to be $< 10^{-26}$.

Comment: In any case, $\epsilon < 1$ is sufficient for the estimate $64 < x < 67$ produced at the end of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but, to approximate the positive root of the equation
\begin{align} 
  \ e^e \cdot x = 10^{10x} \cdot 10^{e^{10x}} 
 \end{align}
you can use numerical methods, as solving it algebraically may be challenging.

Let's use the Newton-Raphson method to approximate the root. The iterative formula for the Newton-Raphson method is given by:

\begin{align}
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} 
\end{align}

Here, $f(x)$ is the function
\begin{align} 
  e^e \cdot x - 10^{10x} \cdot 10^{e^{10x}} ,
 \end{align}
and $f'(x)$ is its derivative.

Let's perform the iterations:

1. **Define the Function and Its Derivative:**
   \begin{align}
   f(x) = e^e \cdot x - 10^{10x} \cdot 10^{e^{10x}},\quad
      f'(x) = e^e - 10^{10x} \cdot 10^{e^{10x}} \cdot \ln(10) \cdot (10 + 1) 
   \end{align}
2. **Initialize the Guess:**
   Start with an initial guess, say $x_0 = 1$.
3. **Iterate:**
   \begin{align}
    x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
   \end{align}

   Perform several iterations until convergence.

**Additionally**, For the equation

\begin{align} 
\ e^{e^x} = 10^{10x} \cdot 10^{e^{10x}} ,
\end{align}
you can use the Lambert $W$ function (product logarithm function) to solve for $x$. The Lambert $W$ function, denoted as $W(x)$, is the inverse function of
\begin{align} 
\ y = xe^x,
\end{align}
and it can be used to solve equations of the form
\begin{align} 
\ xe^x = a.
\end{align}

The equation can be rearranged to the form
\begin{align} 
\ e^x = \frac{1}{10} \cdot 10^{10x} \cdot e^{10x} ,
\end{align}
and then taking the natural logarithm of both sides yields
\begin{align}
\ x = \ln\left(\frac{1}{10} \cdot 10^{10x} \cdot e^{10x}\right) .
\end{align} Further simplification leads to
\begin{align}
\ x = \ln\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) + 10x + \ln\left(e^{10x}\right) 
\end{align}

Now, let \begin{align}
y = 10x
\end{align}
for simplicity, and the equation becomes
\begin{align}
    \ y = \ln\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) + y + 10\ln(y) .
\end{align}

The Lambert $W$ function is defined by
\begin{align}
    \ W(z)e^{W(z)} = z .
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
    \ y = W\left(\frac{1}{10}e^{\ln(1/10)}\right) .
\end{align}
Finally,
$x$ can be found as
\begin{align}
\ x = \frac{1}{10} \cdot y.
\end{align}

Comment: Please add ```$``` dollar sign around math equation to render it.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{10}e^{\ln(1/10)}$ is simply $\frac{1}{100}$. However, that Lambert $W$ value will approximate the small positive solution. Hardy is asking for the "large" one. That can be approximated by the $-1$ branch of the Lambert $W$ function as I mentioned in the comments.